# How can I annotate I want any type as input but something of the same type as output with Flow?

Tags: javascript, typing, flowtype

Say I have a very simple function that simply takes an argument of any type and wraps it in an array.

```
function wrap (anything) {
  return [anything]
}
```

That would be very easily described in (what I understand to be) Hindley-Milner annotation, like this:

```
// wrap :: a -> [a]
```

How would I go about using [Flow](https://flowtype.org)'s type annotation to show this same thing, i.e., that I want any type as input, and an array of that same type as output?

The following does not work:

```
function wrap (anything: a): Array<a> {
  return [anything]
}
```

It throws this error:

```
ERROR in src/wrap.js:1
 1: function wrap(x: a): Array<a> {
                     ^ identifier `a`. Could not resolve name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the syntax for [polymorphic functions](https://flowtype.org/docs/functions.html#polymorphic-functions):

```
function wrap<a>(anything: a): Array<a> {
  return [anything]
}
```